# How to draw rectangles/shapes and import them into PDF table that was generated using ReportLab?

Tags: python, reportlab

I wrote a simple program in python 3.6 that generates a pdf and draws a table with different content in it. The concept is as seen in the code. How can I draw multiple rectangles of different sizes and fill colors and add them to a cell in this table?

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.platypus import Table

data = [
['a', 'b', 'c'],
['where I want to import rectangles', '', ''],
['some data', '', '']

fileName = 'pdfTable.pdf'

pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(
fileName,
pagesize=letter
)

table = Table(data)

elems = []
elems.append(table)
pdf.build(elems)
```

Comment: Have you had a look into the [manual](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) yet? It doesn't seem like a very straight forward package. The `from reportlab.lib.units import inch` function seems to be used for drawing,

Comment: @steTATO I will try to use the pillow library today and see what I can get out of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this post, you can combine use the `reportlab.graphics.shapes` to insert shapes like rectangles directly into a platypus document... Most of the info I am finding online uses the `reportlab.pdfgen.canvas` class to accomplish shape creation, but that is not at all helpful for anyone using `reportlab.platypus.SimpleDocTemplate` which are flowables I think...

Below is some sample code I came up with. It does not accurately draw the rectangle into the table but should answer the difficult part of your original question. In theory you just need to edit the x, y, width, & height to get the desired shape small enough in the table. For more info see the API classes at:

- https://pyng.tech/docs/reportlab/graphics/shapes.m.html#reportlab.graphics.shapes.Rect
- https://pyng.tech/docs/reportlab/graphics/shapes.m.html#reportlab.graphics.shapes.Drawing

```py
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.platypus import Table

from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.graphics import shapes

# setup your platypus document
pdf = SimpleDocTemplate("sample.pdf",
                        pagesize=letter,
                        rightMargin=72,
                        leftMargin=72,
                        topMargin=72,
                        bottomMargin=18)

# create your table from data
data = [
['a', 'b', 'c'],
['where I want to import rectangles', '', ''],
['some data', '', '']]

table = Table(data)

# draw your shapes and add to the platypus doc which is letter 8.5x11 inch
x = 1
y = 8   
width = (8.5-2)*inch # object in points, so we multiply by inch (72 points)
height = 1*inch # object in points, so we multiply by inch (72 points)

# Create your drawing with rectangle 
d = shapes.Drawing(width,height)
r = shapes.Rect(x, y, width, height, fillColor=None, strokeColor=colors.black)
# add the rectangle to your Drawing
d.add(r)

# Setup your Story
Story = []
Story.append(table)
# add the Drawing (i.e. the drawn rectangle) to the platypus doc
Story.append(d)

# Export to PDF
pdf.build(Story)
```